# WebSecurity with multiple databases

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webmatrix

I have a c# mvc.net application that is connected to multiple databases.
To clarify, based on the subdomain of the url, the app will connect to a specific database. This is done by setting the `defaultConnectionFactory` in web.config to a custom implementation of IDbConnectionFactory . This all works fine.

However, i'm having trouble with WebSecurity.
All the WebSecurity functions (eg. Login, CreateAccount, etc) are based on the database initialised at the application startup

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    //other initialisation stuf
```

According to WebMatrix, the `InitializeDatabaseConnection` function should be called once on application startup, and thus always directing to the same database.

What i desire is that depending on the httpRequest, all the WebSecurity stuff would be done on the database linked to the subdomain.

Does anybody have any advice for me how to take on this situation?
Should i override WebSecurity and Initialise it per httpRequest?
Or should i do something with a custom SimpleMembership provider?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In general, this seems like a bad idea.  However, if you have a small number of subdomains, then you could run multiple websites, each handling one of the subdomains.  I don't think the load on the server would be any different.  You'd have the advantage of being able to bring up or down the subdomains independently.  Of course, you'd have to deploy the software multiple times.

Now if you've got a lot of subdomains:   miamiFl.blahblah.com, NewYorkNewYork.blahblah.com... then see my first point again.  Good luck :)

Comment: The whole idea was to have a single app dealing with multiple customers. Each customer whould have their own database (and this works great so far...). A customer could register itself and the app would create the new db. The only issue is that WebSecurity uses a static SimpleMembershipProvider stored in Membership.Provider. I guess i'll have to write a custom membership provider that can deal with multiple memberships